# Python max() function fails when used on pandas columns and integer fails

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I'm trying to create a new pandas dataframe column by subtracting an existing dataframe column column from another. However, if the result is a negative number, the new column value should be set to zero.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [3,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  2
2  3  1
```

If I create a new dataframe column 'C' by subtracting 'B' from 'A', I get the right result.

```
df['C'] = df['A'] - df['B']

In[8]: df
Out[7]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3 -2
1  2  2  0
2  3  1  2
```

However, if I utilize the `max()` function to avoid results with a negative number, I get "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

```
>>> df['C'] = max(df['A'] - df['B'], 0)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The expected output is:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  0
1  2  2  0
2  3  1  2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is recommended output?

Comment: In[8]: df
Out[7]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3 0
1  2  2  0
2  3  1  2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to do element-wise maximum comparison:

```
>>> np.maximum(df['A'] - df['B'], 0)
0    0
1    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

The problem is `max` is that it essentially checks `(df['A'] - df['B']) > 0`. This returns an array of boolean values (not a boolean), hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`:

```
In [8]:
df['C'] = np.where((df['A'] - df['B'] > 0), df['A'] - df['B'], 0)
df

Out[8]:
   A  B  C
0  1  3  0
1  2  2  0
2  3  1  2
```

the in-built `max` function operates on scalars not array-like structures hence the error

Comment: I used your recommended np.where suggestion somewhere else.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do apply:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: max(row['A'] - row['B'], 0), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but instead of using the `max` function:

```
df.max()
```

try to apply `max-function` on the values helped:

```
df.values.max()
```